# Mixing of different sources in the same scripts

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to include a couple of conditions in my code excluding only android visitors. I put this code but the first script in else condition is not working.

```js
    <script type='text/javascript'>
if( /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}else
{
<script type="text/javascript" src="link"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="link"></script>
}

</script>
```

Comment: You can not include script tags inside of script tags....

Comment: Thank you for confirming my doubts. How would be the correct coding? Is this even possible or i have to write a specific condition for every src?

Answer (score 1):

You can't wrap raw html in an `else`

You could add them using `document.write()`

Something like:

```
if( /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}else
{
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="link"></script>');
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="link"></script>');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying your method but still the first script is not active. The second script works properly.

Comment: Well if one works no reason the other shouldn't. Whatever isn't working is probably unrelated to writing the script tags into the document

Comment: i think is a writing error and not a script problem because when i test the script alone it works properly.

Comment: what is even stranger is that when i change the ranking of the scripts (put the first one after the second script (so the actual second changes to first position) the script not working before works now and the one going up does not work anymore

Comment: That sounds more like a problem with what is actually in the scripts

Comment: So i did this and it works but is so bad :<script type="text/javascript">
if( /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}else
{
document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="link1"></script>");
   document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="link2"></script>");
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
if( /Android/.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}else
{
document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="link2"></script>");
document.write("<script type="text/javascript" src="link1"></script>");
}
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

The easiest way to do what you want to achieve is to include all scripts and then execute its content conditionally.

If you can't control the source code of these scripts, then this is a duplicated question of [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)